# Why is getchar() blocking all of the threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading

So, I have this code

```
int main() {

    HttpServer httpserver(8383);
    MyStubServer s(httpserver);

    s.StartListening();

    // getchar();
    for (;;) {
      sleep(60);
    }

    s.StopListening();

    return 0;
}
```

If I don't comment the `getchar();` the server will start but the client will get a request timeout.

Is `getchar();` blocking other threads than my own?

Comment: What framework are you using? Are you sure it's multi-threaded?

Comment: getchar() should not be blocking all threads. What is HttpServer? What is MyStubServer?

Comment: I am using libjsonrpc-cpp and I was just working the example from their github account [here](https://github.com/cinemast/libjson-rpc-cpp)

Comment: @Electron I am almost sure his HttpServer / MyStubServer does run on the same thread as main(), thus a blocking happens.

Comment: MyStunbServer is a class parented from a generated one. See [here](https://github.com/cinemast/libjson-rpc-cpp) ( it is basically the same code I was writing

Answer (score 0):

You might want to run your http server on the different thread:

```
#include <thread>

void runHttpServ()
{
    HttpServer httpserver(8383);
    MyStubServer s(httpserver);

    s.StartListening(); //<- assuming it's a blocking call
}

int main() {

    std::thread t(runHttpServ);

    getchar();

    s.StopListening();
    t.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the question is why is that happening?

Comment: It really depends what StartListening method does. OP says, getchar() cause a client timeout - it means, that a "connection loop" of HttpServer is not run, which is a reason why client request is not handled.